# Unable to "import from lasagne.layers.theta import ThetaLayer" and "from lasagne.layers.timefusion import MaskingLayer"

Tags: python, theano, lasagne

I am trying to reproduce a paper (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5890980/pdf/pone.0195024.pdf)
on predicting hospital readmission. Code at: https://github.com/danicaxiao/CONTENT.

I am stuck in the following line and unable to locate the "ThetaLayer" and "MaskingLayer" in the Lasagne. Not sure how to proceed. Any suggestions would be great help.

[image]

Tried installing latest version of Lasagne.